# ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLType when creating SAP Hana datasource on weblogic

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, weblogic, hana

I configured a datasource in webogic 12.1.3 using the SAP Hana jdbc (ngdbc.jar) version 2.5.49. The connection test works fine in the weblogic console, but when I try to create the entityManagerFactory I get the following error while deploying the application:

```
<Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "42259213886500" for task "0". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLType"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLType
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
```

I have already tried to change ngdbc.jar version to 2.2.x, 2.3.x and 2.4.x but the error doesn't change. Based on some similar questions, it seems that this is a compatibility problem with the JDK the jdbc was build (Java 9), but the SAP Hana documentation and also the jar MANIFEST says it is compiled to Java 6.

This question seems to be a very similar problem, but I tried the version that is built as a multirelease jar (2.3.44) and it didn't work as well.
https://answers.sap.com/questions/492703/is-ngdbc-2333-compatible-with-jvm-8.html

Comment: If you are using a modular project, then make sure you depend on the `java.sql` module.

Comment: Mark, you mean by adding a dependency in my maven pom.xml? What dependency is that? I already have another Data Source (oracle) that works fine without adding any dependency.

Comment: No, it looks like your application is using the Java Module System, which means that to be able to reference `java.sql.Types`, you need to have required the module `java.sql`. This module is part of Java, but if you are using a modular application, it will not be loaded by default. It is also possible that there is some Weblogic specific module logic that is causing the problem, but I have never used Weblogic, so this is all just a guess.

Comment: WebLogic Server 12c does not support (and does not work with java 9)
WebLogic server 14c supports Java 11.